# Graphing $r =2\sin(2\theta)$

Tags: calculus, complex-analysis, integration, residue-calculus

I am calculating some residue calculus stuff, where I need to know if the prescribed poles are inside the curve given above, namely $2\sin(2\theta)$ for $0\leq \theta<2\pi$. I actually need to know if these are $( e^{(\pi i)/4}, e^{(3\pi i)/4},e^{(5\pi i)/4},e^{(7\pi i)/4})$inside the curve or not?

I am actually very bad at graphing, any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: please suggest some sites where I can graph these sort of functions.

Comment: @Nameless, I try to accept all the answers, I accept those which completely make sense to me otherwise I would take time to understand and re-ask. I just don't accept answers sometime thinking that somebody will be there with better and easy approach. I am not trying to be rude, but just don't want to show myself oversmart by accepting the fact which I can not follow.

Comment: I understand your point. Of course you should accept the posts that you can understand and follow, at your own time. 79% is a good percentage. Try to keep it around 80% and people will know that you care about the answers you get

Comment: sounds good. Thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest using FooPlot (free and online). Here is the graph of your polar  [function](http://fooplot.com/#W3sidHlwZSI6MCwiZXEiOiIiLCJjb2xvciI6IiMwMDAwMDAifSx7InR5cGUiOjEsImVxIjoiMnNpbigydGhldGEpIiwiY29sb3IiOiIjMDAwMDAwIiwidGhldGFtaW4iOiIwIiwidGhldGFtYXgiOiIycGkiLCJ0aGV0YXN0ZXAiOiIuMDEifSx7InR5cGUiOjEwMDAsIndpbmRvdyI6WyItNC4xNTYyNSIsIjMuOTY4NzUiLCItMi41MTI0OTk5OTk5OTk5OTk3IiwiMi40ODc1MDAwMDAwMDAwMDAzIl19XQ--). Can you decide now which poles are in the region bounded by the contour? If you want to learn how to graph polar functions yourself I would suggest reading [this](http://www.analyzemath.com/polarcoordinates/graphing_polar_equations.html)

Comment: I think all of the poles inside the graph. This helps a lot. Thanks for the site and plot.

Answer (score 3):

Hint: $e^{pi x}$ has $\theta = x$ and $r = 1$.  What is $\sin(2 \theta)$ when $\theta = \pi/4$, say?

Answer (score 2):

You can use WolframAlpha for the [**plot**](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=polarplot+2Sin+%282theta%29).

Additionally, you can use almost any Computer Algebra System (CAS) and you can find a [**CAS List**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_computer_algebra_systems) here.

Regards

Comment: Short but informative!

Answer (score 1):

You Can use Matlab Program

```
 t=0:pi/100:2*pi;
 r=2*sin(2*t);
 p1=polar(t,r)
 set(p1,'Linewidth',2);
 hold on
 z1=exp(pi*i/4);
 z2=exp(3*pi*i/4);
 z3=exp(5*pi*i/4);
 z4=exp(7*pi*i/4);
 z=[z1 z2 z3 z4];
 p2=polar( angle(z),abs(z),'rx');
 set(p2,'LineWidth',12)
 hold off
 legend('r=2sin(2\theta)','points',-1)
```

[image]

also you can use mathematica

```
   Show[PolarPlot[2 Sin[2 t], {t, 0, 2 Pi}], 
    ListPolarPlot[{{Pi/4, 1}, {3 Pi/4, 1}, {5 Pi/4, 1}, {7 Pi/4, 1}}]]
```

[image]